# Is there a way to only load text for websites?

Tags: nexus-5, 5.1-lollipop

In an attempt to not waste time or data on loading images or videos on website, I've been looking for a way to setup my phone to only load text of a website.  Unfortunately, my Google-fu is failing me here.  How can I set this up?

Comment: If this were a normal desktop-based browser, a personal css file would help here. I'm not sure how this would be performed on an android; root would almost certainly be required in any case.      **#a {}** is probably a good start.

Comment: Perhaps related (though maybe too extreme) http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18709/cannot-get-lynx-browser-to-work

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Download the [UC Mini](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uc.browser.en) Browser App and Install it.

Step 2 : Open it.

Step 3 : Go to the Settings part.

Step 4 : Set the Image Quality to Text-Only.

Step 5 : Enjoy.

Note : This option is only for the app, there is no system-wide option to do so.

Comment: Only problem I have with this browser is that enter on the phone's keyboard just acts like a "hide keyboard" button.  Still, worth it to use when not on WiFi or wanting to speed up load times.